# AWS-CDK: Using InitFile to create a file in EC2 instance

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cdk

I'm trying to create a file in my EC2 instance using the InitFile construct in CDK. Below is the code i'm using to create my EC2 instance into which i'm trying to create a file `textfile.txt` which would contain a text 'welcome' going by https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_ec2/InitFile.html reference
during cdk initialisation,

```
init_data = ec2.CloudFormationInit.from_elements(
            ec2.InitFile.from_string("/home/ubuntu/textfile.txt", "welcome")
        )
```

```
self.ec2_instance = ec2.Instance(self,
            id='pytenv-instance',
            vpc=self.vpc,
            instance_type=ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.BURSTABLE2, ec2.InstanceSize.NANO),
            machine_image=ec2.MachineImage.generic_linux(
                {'us-east-1': 'ami-083654bd07b5da81d'}
            ),
            key_name="demokeyyt18",
            security_group=self.sg,
            vpc_subnets=ec2.SubnetSelection(
                subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC
            ),
            init=init_data,
            
        )
```

From the EC2 configuration it is evident that the machine image here is Ubuntu. Getting this error: `Failed to receive 1 resource signal(s) within the specified duration`.
Am I missing something? Any inputs?

UPDATE: This same code works with EC2 machine image as Amazon_linux but not for Ubuntu. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Looks like the userdata script is failing

Comment: Hey @Paolo any reason why the script might be failing ?

Comment: Check the system logs from the EC2 console, that might give you some hints.

Comment: hi @gshpychka, checked /var/log from the ec2 instance , could not find any errors.

Comment: Can somebody please share their piece of code where they created an initfile for their EC2 instance. Would help me learn a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFormation init requires the presence of `cfn-init` helper script on the instance. Ubuntu does not come with it, so you have to set it up yourself.

[Here's the AWS guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/install-cloudformation-scripts/) that contains links to the installation scripts for Ubuntu 16.04/18.04/20.04. You need to add these to the `user_data` prop of your instance. Then cloudformation-init will work.

If you just want to create a file when the instance starts, though, you don't have to use `cfn-init` at all - you could just supply the command that creates your file to the `user_data` prop directly:

```py
self.ec2_instance.user_data.add_commands("echo welcome > /home/ubuntu/textfile.txt")
```

Comment: Correct! But what if i had larger flask code files/ configuration files to run on my ec2 instance. Obviously, i wouldn't be writing the entire code here , right ?

Comment: That's an unrelated question. But like I said, you can use cfn-init if you need (after setting it up), or, in case of UserData, you can download files from S3. Check the UserData CDK documentation.

Comment: This is also not working , creating an asset in s3 and downloading to ec2 instance,

asset = Asset(self, "Asset", path='pytenv/reverse-proxy.conf')


init=ec2.CloudFormationInit.from_elements(
              ec2.InitFile.from_s3_object(file_name='file.conf', bucket=asset.bucket, key=asset.s3_object_key)),

Comment: Please post a new question, this is unrelated to the problem you described in this question.

Comment: I'm really sorry for that. I should have re iterated correctly.
I'm trying to learn and explore cdk as much as possible. 

Please check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73287777/aws-cdk-downloading-an-asset-to-the-ec2-instance-during-cdk-initialisation